# AngularJS ng-repeat don't see scope variable - in WYSIWYG editor loaded with AJAX?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, view, scope

I'm modifying a website, built with AngularJS, and in one page I have a WYSIWYG editor.

The whole widget that includes the editor, is a div that has 'ng-controller="TextsController"'.

In this div I have a button, clicking on it displays the editor. And the initializing of the editor happens in a directive - "richTextEditor".

So - I'm making a popup in this editor, that has to show some images from the server. I put the code for pulling the images in the controller ... and there I set

```
$http.get('/url/to/files').success(function(data) {

  $scope.imagesFromServer = data;

});
```

and in the view I have

```
'ng-repeat="image in imagesFromServer"'
```

And the problem is that the ngRepeat doesn't see any items.

I have two ideas:

1. The view, containing the ngRepeat (the HTML for the editor, and the popup with the images as well) loads with AJAX, and at that very moment the scope variable is not set.
2. I'm initializing the scope variable in the wrong place. (Eventually has to be in the directive instead of the controller? ... but all examples I've seen and done so far - pull every data in the controller, and the view sees it directly.)

Hope I've described the situation clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't it `'ng-repeat="image in imagesFromServer"'` ?

Comment: Yes, it is `imagesFromServer` in the code :) I'm gonna edit the question right away :) ...

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet or Plunker link that illustrates your problem?